# Adjusting a function's input, from a string to a dataframe

Tags: r, string, function, dataframe, vector

I have a column ISBN on my data (no NA's present) each filled with a string of length 10. I check the structure of my column like this and I get:

```
str(ISBN) 

Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   20824 obs. of  1 variable:
$ ISBN: chr  "1319078575" "1319078575" "1319080790" "1319080790" ...
```

Now, I made a function that takes as an input a string of length 10 (an ISBN) and checks whether it's valid or not and outputs TRUE or FALSE. According to my tests works fine (I think).

```
ValidateISBN <-  function(x){
  isbnum <- unlist(strsplit(x,split = NULL))
  if(tail(isbnum, n = 1) == "X"){
    isbnum[10] <- 10
  }
  x <- as.numeric(isbnum)
  y <- c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
  innerprod <- sum(x*t(y))
  if(innerprod %% 11 == 0){
    x = TRUE
  }
  else{
    x = FALSE
  }
  return(x)
}
```

I tried these checks:

```
#Testing my function:

a <- "131908057X"
b <- "1319080529"
c <- "1319078575"

ValidateISBN(a)
ValidateISBN(b)
ValidateISBN(c)
```

and they worked. So my next (naive) step was to try pass my ISBN column to my function and hoped as an output for a column-like of same lenght as ISBN sequence of TRUE's and FALSE's. But it didn't work. What adjustment(s) should I make to my function in order to be able to pass an entire column? Thank you.

If this is not something that I can do (excuse my ignorance I am a beginner) could I change/temporarily alter my df column so I can pass it's elements (rows) into the function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also simply apply your function element-wise using `sapply`. A working example is given below, I also added an invalid ISBN for illustration purposes:

```
# sample data
a <- "131908057X"
b <- "1319080529"
c <- "1319078575"
d <- "9999999990"
df = data.frame(ISBN=c(a,b,c,d),stringsAsFactors = F)

df$valid = sapply(df$ISBN, ValidateISBN)
```

which returns:

```
        ISBN valid
1 131908057X  TRUE
2 1319080529  TRUE
3 1319078575  TRUE
4 9999999990 FALSE
```

Hope this helps!

---

Alternatively, but less nice in my opinion, you could rewrite your function as

```
ValidateISBN <-  function(X){
  result = rep(FALSE, length(X))
  for(i in 1:length(X))
  {
    x = X[i]
    isbnum <- unlist(strsplit(x,split = NULL))
    if(tail(isbnum, n = 1) == "X"){
      isbnum[10] <- 10
    }
    x <- as.numeric(isbnum)
    y <- c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
    innerprod <- sum(x*t(y))
    if(innerprod %% 11 == 0){
      x = TRUE
    }
    else{
      x = FALSE
    }
    result[i] = x
  }
  return(result)
}
```

in which case you could call it as

```
ValidateISBN(df$ISBN)
```

But there will not be a real speed difference. To achieve that, you would also have to vectorize the internals of your function.

Comment: You could also use `Vectorize()` to make a vectorized version of the function (basically it just wraps the `sapply` for you.)

Comment: I get this error, do you know what could it mean? Error in strsplit(x, split = NULL) : non-character argument Does it mean that allong my df of strings there is a row or rows that are not strings? Or could it mean something else? This is what I get after the sapply.

Comment: That probably means that your column is of class factor instead of character. Try `sapply(as.character(df$ISBN), ValidateISBN)`